# Как лучше всего добавлять текст на страницу?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, текст, веб-сайт

Не совсем понимаю чем лучше пользоваться при добавлении текста на страницу, знаю разные теги p, div,
h и т.д. но какой и когда лучше использовать не понимаю, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно на опыте со временем наработать некоторые "хорошие практики". Но однозначной истины в этом вопросе нет.

С одной стороны, можно использовать только `div`, придавая ему нужные стили для конкретных ситуаций. Всё будет работать хорошо. Так же как например с `p`, `span` и прочими подобными тегами.

С другой стороны кроме визуальной составляющей есть ещё очень много нюансов, например индексирование поисковиками, доступность, быстрое понимание кода.

Поэтому первое, что советую сделать, это прочесть назначение тегов в разных источниках (не в одном, а много где). Например [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) говорится:

> HTML-элемент `<p>` представляет собой абзац

Не просто текст, не просто одна строчка, не одно слово или буква. А абзац. Если у вас не абзац, а название продукта или подсказка из трёх слов, то это не повод использовать тег `p`. Лучше подойдёт `div` или `span`.

Но, как я писал выше, мнения есть разные. Кому-то удобно считать тег `p` подходящим для любых слов. С этим в большинстве случаев нет никаких проблем.

После прочтения назначения тегов, в случае когда не знаете что применить, просто пишите `div`. Позже вы сможете улучшить это место или сделать правильнее в следующем сайте.

Answer (score 1):

Смотря для чего вам нужен текст. Если заголовок - `h1-6`, если как текст, то `p`. `div` вообще не используется для добавления текста. Он - контейнер и нужен для того, чтобы правильно разметить(распределить) области страницы между другими элементами. То есть, у вас есть меню(хэдер), контент и футер и вам надо их разместить в правильном порядке + чтобы элементы имели свою определённую область. Тогда обращайтесь к `div`

Comment: Спасибо, подойдет ли div для того чтобы разместить информацию в нужном порядке только в хэдере или например только в футере?

Comment: @dhelfy, боюсь неточно понял ваш вопрос. Уточните, пожалуйста